# Data grid headings displace when browser width is adjusted

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an Angular application that has a particular page with a number of rows of data that are generated by *ngFor, these rows look like a table in the sense that each row has similar elements that display a name, description, and have some action buttons. However the data is not stored in a table. The data can also not be stored in a table due to each row being an expansion panel that houses a lot of information within itself and reworking these into a table would probably take too much time.

I need to create a header for this "table", but obviously I can't just do it in the normal way by using table headers. Instead I need to create a separate element that sits above the "table" and has a number of child elements that are positioned in such a way that it gives the impression that it's a header for the series of rows below it.

I've tried doing this in several ways; flexbox, grid, etc but every time I have the same problem with my header. The problem is that when I have the headers aligned properly over the columns if the width of the browser is changed the headers then become unaligned.

I have created a stackblitz to showcase this, here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzazjx?file=src/app/app.component.css

In this example "header 1" should be above "Info" and "header 2" the right-most button. If you adjust the window and make it very big or very small the headers will move around and become misaligned. For example as a very small width "heading 1" will move to be above the left most button. In a similar sense if the browser width is increased the heading will move to the right instead of staying fixed

Is there a way to fix these headers above the elements I want them above such that if the window is changed they will stay fixed above the correct elements and will not displace themselves? I'm all out of ideas as nothing seems to work.

HTML

```
<div class="test-holder">
    <div class="card test-container1">
        <h4 class="heading1">Heading 1</h4>
        <h4 class="heading2">Heading 2</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="card d-flex test-container2">
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h2>Info</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h4>More Info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Another button</button>
        </div>

    </div>
  <div class="card d-flex test-container2">
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h2>Info</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h4>More Info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Another button</button>
        </div>

    </div>
  <div class="card d-flex test-container2">
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h2>Info</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h4>More Info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Another button</button>
        </div>

    </div>
  <div class="card d-flex test-container2">
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h2>Info</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h4>More Info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Another button</button>
        </div>

    </div>
  <div class="card d-flex test-container2">
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h2>Info</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <h4>More Info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <p>This is some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
            <button>Another button</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test-holder {
  width: 100%;
}

.test-container1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.test-container2 {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.heading1 {
  width: 28%;
  text-align: right;
}

.heading2 {
  width: 68%;
  text-align: right;
}
.card {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you aren't using a table. This seems like a fine use-case, and it might resolve your issue.

Comment: @isherwood Largely because there was a developer before me working on this who didn't decide to use a table (I would have), and now converting it over to a table view would like be a bit too much work for the allotted time I have.